# MySQL get result of stmt result for dynamic query

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get the result of the dynamic query to use in my IF condition, but I always get this error message `Error Code: 1210 Incorrect arguments to EXECUTE`

What I want to happen is if the content of the column is empty, it will not add 100 to the totalamt column.

help me improve or solve my code if you have other solution or way for this problem.

**Here is my code:**

```
        set total = 20;
        set x = 0;
        set counter = 1;
        WHILE (x < total) DO

        SET @cGuest = (CONCAT('name', counter));
        SET @nGuest = CONCAT('SELECT ',@cGuest,' into @c1 FROM guest WHERE ',iEmpID,' = idemp;');

        PREPARE stmt FROM @nGuest;
        SET @c1 = c2;
        EXECUTE stmt; --  USING @c1;
        SELECT @c1 as result;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

        IF @c1 != '' or ' ' or NULL THEN

        UPDATE employee 
        SET 
        totalamt = totalamt + 100
        WHERE
        iEmpID = idemp;




        set x = x + 1;
        set counter = counter + 1;

        ELSE SELECT 'ERROR';
        set x = x + 1;
        set counter = counter + 1;



        END IF;
        END WHILE;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have an incorrect usage of [SELECT...INTO](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html)

Please try this:

```
SET @nGuest = CONCAT('SELECT ',@cGuest,' into @c1 FROM guest WHERE ',iEmpID,' = idemp;');
```

Comment: Problem solved! thanks mate! but I am now having a problem for the infinite loop.

Comment: No problem @VinceOsana, glad to help